# How to pivot one column in Snowflake without rest of the table?

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table:

| ID | Device | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Fridge | A |
| 02 | Fridge | B |
| 03 | Oven | A |
| 04 | Oven | B |

And i want it to look like this:

| ID | Device | Type A | Type B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Fridge | 1 | NULL |
| 02 | Fridge | NULL | 1 |
| 03 | Oven | 1 | NULL |
| 04 | Oven | NULL | 1 |

Is it possible to write such query in Snowflake, without using PowerQuery to pivot this column?

I tried standard pivoting options, but non of the results where even close to my case. Maybe there is another method to achieve that using SQL?

Comment: Plz share your attempt

Comment: What have you tried? Looks like you might solve with `CASE` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really doing any pivoting. You can achieve it using simple IFF function:

```
create or replace table test (
  id varchar, 
  device varchar, 
  type varchar
);

insert into test values 
  ('01', 'Fridge', 'A'), 
  ('02', 'Fridge', 'B'), 
  ('03', 'Oven', 'A'), 
  ('04', 'Oven', 'B');

select 
    id, 
    device,  
    IFF(type = 'A', 1, NULL) as type_a,
    IFF(type = 'B', 1, NULL) as type_b
from test;

+----+--------+--------+--------+
| ID | DEVICE | TYPE_A | TYPE_B |
|----+--------+--------+--------|
| 01 | Fridge |      1 |   NULL |
| 02 | Fridge |   NULL |      1 |
| 03 | Oven   |      1 |   NULL |
| 04 | Oven   |   NULL |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```